# Servlet in Eclipse: The requested resource [/Register/] is not available

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

Exact error: The requested resource [/Register/] is not available. Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I am using tomcat and Eclipse.

Here is the code:

RegisterDao.java

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class RegisterDao {
    
    private String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/explorecalifornia";
    private String dbUname = "dbuser";
    private String dbPassword = "dbpassword";
    private String dbDriver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    
    public void loadDriver(String dbDriver)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUname, dbPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
    
    
    public String insert(Member member)
    {
        loadDriver(dbDriver);
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String result = "Data entered successfully";
        String sql = "insert into member values(?,?,?,?)";
        
        PreparedStatement ps;
        try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, member.getUname());
        ps.setString(2, member.getPassword());
        ps.setString(3, member.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4, member.getPhone());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "Data not entered";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Register.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Register() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        
        Member member = new Member(uname, password, email, phone);
        
        RegisterDao rDao = new RegisterDao();
        String result = rDao.insert(member);
        response.getWriter().print(result);
        
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Registration</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>memberRegistration.jsp</welcome-file>
    
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and memberRegistration.jsp

```
  
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="memberRegistration" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>User Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="uname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>phone: </td><td><input type="text" name="phone"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="register"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is Your action name is correct in jsp file. i.e is this to be "Register" instead of "memberRegistration" ? Can you mention the package structure for files?

Comment: I just tried changing the action in jsp to be memberRegistration but it didn't change anything

Comment: It should be "Register" - can you tell me the package name under which your java classes are placed?

Comment: they're in no package../default/src

Comment: added as answer , is that worked?

Comment: not yet, I am trying both the package and rename the action will update if it does

Answer (score 0):

Need to place the servlet class in a java package. You should always put publicly reusable Java classes in a package, otherwise they are invisible to classes which are in a package, such as the server itself.

Comment: They are in a package now, it still says Register is not found